# Is there a way to represent BC dates with java.util.date?

Tags: java, datetime, java.util.date

Yes, I understand that java.util.Date is extremely outdated. That being said, is there a way to represent dates before 1 CE using this class, or must I migrate to a different class?

Comment: I don't see why not. what have you tried?

Comment: @njzk2 Date doesn't represent dates, hence trivially the answer is 'it cannot' (I guess the name threw you off. Understandable).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And yes, it represents dates back to nearly a billion years BC just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trivially, no. **There is no way to represent dates with `java.util.Date` at all. Any date.**

`j.u.Date` is a misnomer, and is obsolete API you should not be using. It actually represents an instant in time, unconnected to a timezone, and therefore, unconnected to the concept of years, months, and days. That's why e.g. `.getYear()` is deprecated, and why the only field that `j.u.Date` has is a long containing epochmillis.

You must migrate to [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html). Specifically, [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Note that you can represent moments in time that, once you place them in a timezone, are before 1CE just fine. epochmillis-in-a-long (which is what `System.currentTimeMillis()` represents, and for which `j.u.Date` is a really really bad wrapper, but `java.time.Instant` is the right thing to use if you want that) - their range is a few million years in both directions.